# Searching by query and location in Grails app

Tags: search, grails, grails-searchable

I am using the searchable plugin in my grails application to search for "Offering" instances in the following way.

Search setup with following mapping in Offering class

```
class Offering {

    static searchable = {
        only: ['title', 'description']
    }

    String title
    String description

    Category category
    Location location

    BigDecimal price
    PricePeriod pricePeriod

    static belongsTo = [user: SecUser]

    static constraints = {
        title(blank: false, maxSize: 100)
        description(blank: false, maxSize: 10240)
        category(nullable: false)
        location(nullable: false)
        price(nullable: true, scale: 2)
        pricePeriod(nullable: true)
    }

    public String toString() {
        return title
    }

}
```

Call to searchable service

```
 def search = {
    must(queryString(params.query))
 }

 def searchResult = searchableService.search(search, params)
```

As expected this returns appropriate hits from the mapped properties of Offering instances. A collection of offerings

What I would like to do now is search not only by the search query but also the Offerings child element of location. Specifically the "locationName" field within the child Location instance.

So if I search by query "dinner" and location "Brisbane" I would like to get a collection of offerings matching "dinner" with a child location instance with the "locationName" property matching "Brisbane"

Any ideas on where to start to implement something like this using the searchable plugin?

Location class

```
class Location {

    String locationName
    Location locationParent
    String postcode

    static hasMany = [locations: Location]

    static constraints = {
        locationName(blank: false, unique: true)
        locationParent(nullable: true)
        postcode(nullable: true)
    }

    public String toString() {
        return locationName
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is something along the lines of:

```
class Offering {

   ...

   static searchable = {
       only: ['title', 'description']
       location component: true
   }

   ...
}
```

and

```
class Location {

    ...

    static searchable = {
       only: ['locationName']
       location component: true
    }

    ...
}
```